# Update data behind chart in powerpoint through office.js add-in

Tags: office365, powerpoint, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I am using the new Office.js API for PowerPoint. I've inspected the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint?view=powerpoint-js-preview) but couldn't find what I was looking for.

I want to know if it possible to **update the data behind an existing chart using Office.js**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Office.js may not provide a direct method for changing the data source of an existing chart, However, you can do it by creating a new chart and replacing the existing one with the updated / new data:-

```
Office.onReady(function (info) {
    if (info.host === Office.HostType.PowerPoint) {
        // Register event handlers and interact with PowerPoint here
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Replace "YourChartTitle" with the title of the chart you want to update.
            var chartTitle = "YourChartTitle";
            var newChartData = [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]
            ]; // Replace with your new data

            PowerPoint.run(function (context) {
                // Get the current slide
                var currentSlide = context.presentation.slides.getActiveSlide();

                // Get the existing chart
                var existingChart = currentSlide.shapes.getByName(chartTitle);

                // Delete the existing chart
                existingChart.delete();

                // Insert a new chart with the updated data
                var newChart = currentSlide.shapes.addChart(Office.MailboxEnums.ChartType.ColumnClustered, newChartData, "A1:C3");

                return context.sync();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This one is really interesting, I am not able to find the above functions in the official documentation and when I try to use them it raises error, like getActiveSlide is not defined, is is possible that you are mixing VSB/.NET API with JS API?